# Lucene query: increasing performance

Tags: performance, search, lucene

I'm using Lucene.NET version 2.9.4.

I need to build a complex query. I need to find hotels around a point.
To do it I know the latitude/longitude of any my hotels and the geoCoordinate of my referiment point.

Lucene can't do math, so I will build the searchQuery with some `range` filter.

Example:

```
(
  (latitude:[45 TO 55] AND longitude:[5 TO 95])
  OR (latitude:[40 TO 60] AND longitude:[20 TO 80])
  OR (latitude:[25 TO 75] AND longitude:[25 TO 75])
  OR ...
)
```

The query will be long, then I fear that the query can take too many time to elaborate.

But I have idea: I add a `inclusive filter` to exclude all hotels too many far from my point.

Example:

```
(
    (latitude:[0 TO 100] AND longitude:[0 TO 100])
    AND (
      (latitude:[45 TO 55] AND longitude:[5 TO 95])
      OR (latitude:[40 TO 60] AND longitude:[20 TO 80])
      OR (latitude:[25 TO 75] AND longitude:[25 TO 75])
      OR ...
    )
)
```

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was tested.

The second solution is not more fast of first.
I used 232000 nodes.